# How To Extract Only Number From String Having chars & date as well as numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a field in sql

```
NAME :

5010001918/2/03/000 DATED:20.12.2013                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

5010002069/2/03/00   DATED:29.04.2014                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

ADV NO:5210041376/2/03/00 DATED:06.01.2015                                                                                                                                                                                                                     

LICENCE NO-5010002165/2/03/00 DATE:-14.11.2015
```

I want output :

```
5010001918/2/03/000

5010002069/2/03/00

5210041376/2/03/00

5010002165/2/03/00
```

I tried substring part but it doesn't seems to be working.

Comment: Depends on your DB engine. Split the string on space and `:`

Comment: I am using sql 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try if sqlserver

```
select  substring(your_column,patindex('%[0-9]%',@n),19) from yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use substring

```
    select  substring(your_column,1,instr(your_column," ") -1) my_value,  
    from tablename;
```